# iOS: Setting properties

Tags: ios, pointers, pointer-address

When I'm setting a property with an object that is currently in a retained NSArray, will it only store the pointer (light-weight), or will it copy the contents to the property?

From what I know, it seems like it would only assign the pointer, but I'm not sure.

Also, under what circumstances would using *pointer = *otherPointer or the set methods (setDelegate, for instance) copy the value, instead of just passing the pointer, if any.
Shouldn't it always just pass the pointer address?

Comment: I don't mean to sound snarky, but it depends upon how the `@property` is defined. If it's defined with `copy` it will copy it. If not, it won't. If I'm not understanding your question, let me know. As an aside, technically, the property is always getting a pointer (if it has the asterisk), but it's just a question of whether the pointer is pointing to the same thing, or a copy of that thing, and whether the object has its `retainCount` increased or not.

Comment: Yeah. So, it will only copy it if its a property with the 'copy' attribute? Ivars are strictly pointer translations as well?

Comment: Re `copy` attribute, yes. Re ivars, not sure if I understand the question, but wherever you see the asterisk associated with some object var name, it's really just a pointer to something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It always passes the pointer, as you said. Unless you are specifically adding a de-referencing sign, this will always be the case.

However, when you add a property to a class, and set the setter to `copy`:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) id obj;
```

When using the dot syntax or the setter, This will be translated to:

```
_obj = [otherObj copy];
```

Here, it will depend whether the object in question supports copying itself, or will it fall back to it's super class `NSObject` or another intermediate class's copy.

Moreover, Collection classes `NSDictionary` and `NSArray` do a shallow copy, as in they copy the references to their objects only, so you have two collections pointing to the same set of objects.

Comment: Well, copy is really for mutable objects. If you ask an array to copy itself, you get the original. if you ask a mutable array, you will get a new array with the objects of the original. Likewise with a string. Frankly, I don't use copy enough - its REALLY a good idea to use it for things that are often provided to you as mutable (even though the method may declare itself as returning a non mutable array, it can (and will) in some cases return a mutable one. Some of the OSX interfaces which declare -(NSString). If in doubt use "copy" and it gives protection while have virtually no cost.

Comment: Unless if the copied array is massive, right? Maybe a large image array, or whatnot. Its an outlier, but its something you would want to avoid.